# Using the public ip in a bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, ip

I'm writing a bash script to send in the user-data of an ec2 instance that I will launch dynamically. The script needs to use the instance ip, which I don't have until the instance is launched and runs the script. 
So the script should be something like

```
"#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST .....blablabla.........
{
     "serverIp": HERE I NEED THE CURRENT INSTANCE IP,
}'
```

I know that doing curl to http://127.0.0.1/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 you get the ip but given other factors, I can't use an http call to itself.

Is there any easy way of retrieving the ip from the bash script?

Thank you!!

Comment: See: [Finding the Public IP address in a shell script](http://serverfault.com/q/89114/234750) (23 Answers)

Comment: Yeah, but that just wants to see the ip, I need to use it in a script.

Comment: If I for example write "#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST .....blablabla.........
{
     "serverIp": curl ifconfig.me,
}'

it won't work.

Comment: You are mistaken about 127.0.0.1.  The correct address is [169.254.169.254](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html), as noted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using curl

`` IP_ADDR=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
echo $IP_ADDR ``

other answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

Insert call call-out to curl:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST .....blablabla.........
{
     "serverIp": `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`,
}'
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It didn't recognize `. But still helped because I used it to take it to a variable outside. +1

Answer (score 0):

With dig:

```
#!/bin/bash

serverIp=$(dig +time=1 +tries=1 +retry=1 +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
echo $serverIp
```